# Module XML with multiple search result web part are conflicting

Tags: web-part, search-results, elements-xml, module

I have a module file which contains two search result web part. These two search result web part were both configured then exported as .webpart file via the SP UI. I used the exact content of the .webpart file to define my search result web parts in the module. When I load the page initially, one of the webpart will fail, upon refreshing one to three times the issue is gone. The problem is that this happens even when cache is cleared.

The two search result web part is connected to two separate search box. Which is correct when I check the properties. I cannot find anything on the ULS log either, correlation ID is always 00000-0000...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to replicate the issue using out of the box. It seems that having two search boxes and two search results is not a viable way to do things. I used result sources and search navigation instead to have a multi-tab view of the search result.

The good thing with the multi-tab approach is that the page looks cleaner as I am only maintaining one search box and one search result on the page.

The down side of multi-tab approach is that I have to manage two separate pages containing the exact components except for the search result web part connected to a different result source.